# Uitableview displaying objects

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to display the values of a `NSMutableArray` in a `UITableView`. In the `NSMutableArray` are values of objects. But the `UITableView` doesn't display anything. If I use a normal `NSArray` with static values it works well.

So this is my code:

This is my object

```
@interface Getraenke_Object : NSObject {
    NSString *name;
}
```

my `NSMutableArray`

```
NSMutableArray *getraenkeArray;

here is where I get the values into the array:
for(int i = 0; i < [getraenkeArray count]; i++)
    {    
        [_produktName addObject:[[getraenkeArray objectAtIndex:i]getName]];
        NSLog(@"test: %@",_produktName);
    }
```

and that is how I try to display it in the `UITableView`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProduktCell";
    ProduktTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ProduktTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    int row = [indexPath row];

    cell.produktName.text = _produktName [row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: you are not defining _productName  array anywhere but you are only using it, make sure you are declaring it as NSMutableArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your getraenkeArray as member and:

```
cell.produktName.text = [[getraenkeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] getName];
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you never allocated the NSMutableArray. you are missing:

```
_produktName = [NSMutableArray array];
```

and that's why the addObject is being sent to nil..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I did that:
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *produktName;

In the NSLog everything works well too...

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs answer is the best, because it simplifies your code.  but just to make sure you understood my answer for the future: judging by your comment it seems that you still haven't allocated and initialized the mutable array. declaring it as a (nonatomic, strong) property isn't enough..